# Best way to read logic from JSON file and apply specific logic using spark scala

Tags: json, apache-spark, hadoop, transform

I have an initial data frame that is created by reading a `JSON` file. Now I have `config` like below:

```
{
"sourceField":"id",
"transformLogic":"where id>=10"
"targetField":"patientId"
}
```

So, what I did is I read this config file, took first value of "`transformLogic`" field, and using spark SQL I generated the query and executed it against the initial JSON data frame. However, I am not satisfied with that because the string of `transformLogic` is hardcoded by me and it should be dynamic. Its something like read the config file, apply the specific logic against the `sourceField` and it should be reflected in the target field in the transformed data frame. How can I make it dynamic that would use `sourceField` and `targetField`

I need some suggestions to implement this approach. I can take care of the coding part. I hope I am clear enough to explain my problem.

Comment: first of all your json is quite confusing, you can not apply whereclause on any `sourceField` column to get  `targetField`. If your intention is  to `1. get the json DF 2. read the config 3. convert the sourceField from input df -> targetField` then transformLogic must be a column level operation like `case when..then..else..end`

Comment: in that case you can have naive approach like define json - `{
"sourceField":"id",
"transformLogic":"case when ($sourceField$  >=10) then 'Y' else 'N' end "
"targetField":"patientId"
}` , here you need to load the dataframe from the source and run `inputDF.withColumn($targetField, functions.expr(transformLogic.replaceAll("$sourceField$", $sourceField)))`

Comment: Okay. I understood what you are trying to say over here. I just had one doubt that when we use `case.. when.. then..` at the end we can give an alias. so here is it okay if I modify your code something like this `{ "sourceField":"id", "transformLogic":"case when ($sourceField$  >=10) then 'Y' else 'N' end  as $targetField", "targetField":"patientId" }` and after I run this logic by `spark.sql` I will just delete the original `id` column if I want.

Comment: Yeah you can do that

Comment: I think for your use case scala meta library is good choice  - https://scalameta.org/ check this , spark also using internally.

Comment: Ok bro. let me check it once.

Comment: above library is used to write any function or classes inside string & at run time it will generate code for that, compile & execute.

Comment: Yeah little bit confusing but let me go through it once. I ll ping you if I need more clarity on this bro. @Srinivas

Comment: one more why are you using this field - "transformLogic":"where id>=10", instead split this into two, like condition ">=" & its value 10. you know field already "id" is in "sourceField" .. reason is user might give you wrong field(not in json) instead of id say some thing like "name" field.. you have to add extra validation on that.

Comment: Yup this sounds good actually but what if somebody doesn't want to enter the value. How can we handle that field then?

Comment: just think without filter value from user, how will you decide which data to take.. there might be some value either number or date ?? what do you say ?

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. If there is a where clause then there has to be a value for  the specific field on which data would be filtered out.

Comment: if config is not having filed names throw an exception if that field is required or use your default column. & always maintain default columns if config has columns use those else it should fall back to default value for safer side.

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. Let me propose this and see what are the different thoughts. Thanks for your inputs bro. Much appreciated :)